# Cannot create Safe from at https://dev.gnosis-safe.io/

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to create a Safe App, and am following this tutorial
https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build-with-safe/sdks/safe-apps/testing-your-safe-app

It pointed me to
https://dev.gnosis-safe.io/

where I'm suppose to be able to create a Safe, but I get an error, when following these steps

Steps

1. Visit https://dev.gnosis-safe.io/
2. Connect address
3. Attempt to "Create Safe"

Result

4.

```
TypeError: b is undefined
    e Welcome.tsx:88
    c runtime.js:63
    _invoke runtime.js:293
    E runtime.js:118
    [...]
    e Welcome.tsx:112
```

[image: aats]

Expected

4. Can proceed in creating a Safe successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy contracts first and only then create a Safe.

The developer interface is only meant for networks not supported by the production interface. I can see that you're connected to Rinkeby, so you can use the production interface for testing your app.